# VB.NET multiple picturebox randomizer

Tags: vb.net, random, picturebox, imagelist

I want to create a form in which will be displayed a question and the user will have to chose the correct out of four images..

First of all I'm using an ArrayList and fill it with my questions, I'm also creating two Imagelists. I'm adding all the correct "answers" in order (ex the correct answer for the first question ( Arraylist1(0) ) will be the first Image ( Imagelist1 (0) ). The second Imagelist is full of "wrong" answers. Up to this point everything works fine.

I want the Images to appear in random order, so I tried to create a temporary list and fill it with the Correct Image and three wrong in randomly... 
But I couldn't find out how to do that... Since "Contains" and "ImagelistA.Images.Add(ImagelistB(3))" are not working as I thought that they would...

PS: Following the same pattern for Arraylists instead of Imagelists worked perfectly... But I can't figure out a way to have the same outcome with Images...

```
     Public Sub reloadForm()

    'Filling the ArrayList with questions'
    Dim questions As New ArrayList
    questions.Add("Question1")
    questions.Add("Question2")
    questions.Add("Question3")
    questions.Add("Question4")
    questions.Add("Question5")
    questions.Add("Question6")

    Dim Randm As New Random
    Dim rnd As New Integer
    Dim temp As New ImageList
    Dim flaG As Boolean

    flaG = False

    'Picking a random unanswered question from the ArrayList'
    'Adds the Correct Image/Answer to a Temporary List'
    Do
        rnd = Randm.Next(0, (questions.Count))
        If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(rnd) Then
            question.Text = questions(rnd)
            temp.Images.Add(ImageListC(rnd))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(rnd)
            flaG = True
        End If
    Loop Until flaG = True

    'Adding three wrong Images/Answers in to Temporary Imagelist'
    Do
        rnd = Randm.Next(0, (ImageListW.Images.Count))
        If Not temp.Contains(ImageListW(rnd)) Then
              temp.Images.Add(ImageListW(rnd))
        End If
    Loop Until temp.Count = 4

    'Displays all four Images in a random order'
    Dim quizlist As New Imagelist
        Do
            rnd = Randm.Next(0, 4)
            If Not quizlist.Contains(tempList(rnd)) Then
                quizlist.Images.Add(tempList(rnd))
            End If
        Loop Until quizList.Count = 4

        PictureBox1.Image = quizlist(0)
        PictureBox2.Image = quizlist(1)
        PictureBox3.Image = quizlist(2)
        PictureBox4.Image = quizlist(3)
End Sub
```

Can you suggest a solution for this one, or a different way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Can you suggest a solution` a solution for what?  You didnt tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I believe that the explanation is way better not...

Comment: First, an imagelist is a Component usually used to map images to a ListView or menu item not a temp variable.  Second, your second Do/Loop may well add the same image more than once (including the first one picked).  What you really need is a Shuffle - put some known things in random order, and thise *things* just need to be integers representing an index in the main/real ImageList

Comment: When I did the same using Arraylist instead of Imagelist, this did the trick and every Image was added once due to "Contains" atribute...

So I guess that using Imagelists is not that good as I thought.. I'll  try to find out if I can do it in a different way...

Thanks for your response